# Embedding CSS styles?

Tags: css

I'm curious as to if there's a way to do something like this:

```
#sidemenu {
  .unlocked {
    color: blue;
  }

  .locked {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

instead of having to write it out like:

```
#sidemenu .unlocked {
    color: blue;
}

#sidemenu .locked {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: research about [**SASS**](http://sass-lang.com/) SCSS

Comment: You're in for a magical discovery.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have CSS like this natively, but you can write it initially using CSS pre-processors such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). The code is then compiled down to normal CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Switch from vanilla css to [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Here's a small example between vanilla CSS and SCSS:

**Vanilla CSS:**

```
#sidemenu .unlocked {
    color: blue;
}

#sidemenu .locked {
    color:red;
}
```

**SCSS:**

```
#sidemenu
    .unlocked {
        color: blue;
    }

    .locked {
        color:red;
    }
}
```

---

As Scott mentioned above, the SASS/SCSS/LESS will be recompiled to Vanilla CSS once it's rendered though.